# Behaviour of default_search_timeout on elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to understand how the following elastic-search setting works:

```
search.default_search_timeout
```

I tried to configure this value on a cluster but I couldn't actually limit down to a desired level the time a query takes. The timeout occurs and a query gets stopped but still lasts longer than expected. It seems that there is some relation of `default_search_timeout` value to the actual occurring timeout but it doesn't feel like a linear relation, or anyway I don't understand how it works. I got `2m` lasting queries for a `15s` `default_search_timeout` configuration.

Any ideas on how to understand better this topic?

**All I need is to restrict a long-lasting kibana query from overloading my elastic-search cluster.**

Other ideas would be much appreciated.

Note: Using elasticsearch version `2.2.0` and applied the setting via REST api (in the transient group)

Comment: have you made this settings in config file or made via Api?

Comment: and also please mention the elasticsearch version you are using

Comment: I did this on version 2.2.0 via REST API (I applied this to the transient config)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The timeout value is checked when search moves from one segment to another. i.e. at the end boundary of a segment. On exceeding the timeout value it will be cancelled during this scan

So if you have a large segment and lets say it takes 2m for the search to scan the first segment till the end then the search will be cancelled at 2m

There is another setting to overcome this behaviour. To quote ES docs.
[Search Timeout & Cancellation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.2/search.html#global-search-cancellation)

> Searches can be cancelled using standard task cancellation mechanism.
> By default, a running search only checks if it is cancelled or not on
> segment boundaries, therefore the cancellation can be delayed by large
> segments. The search cancellation responsiveness can be improved by
> setting the dynamic cluster-level setting
> search.low_level_cancellation to true. However, it comes with an
> additional overhead of more frequent cancellation checks that can be
> noticeable on large fast running search queries. Changing this setting
> only affects the searches that start after the change is made.